# How to install dbx?

Tags: installation, debugging

I use `dbx` on an AIX server and I would like to use it on my ubuntu 12.04 too. How do I get it?

Answer (score 2):

From Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or type this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ddd
```

In ubuntu dbx is included in ddd . 
view man page for more details 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ddd.1.html

Comment: Is it a debugging tool? Doesn't seem so..